# Keep getting "Cannot access memory at address 0x0" for node2 till node5

Tags: c++, linked-list, gdb

I looked through other posts about this problem and the reason seems to be not allocating memories/ dereferencing correctly. The output only shows data stored in the first node, which is created in the Main function. However, I am allocating every new node using `new`. Below is my code if someone could please take a look:

```
struct people{
    Name name;
    double height;
    int weight;
};
struct Queue{
    people* ppl;
    int data;
    Queue* next;
};

void print(Queue * queueHead){
    Queue * traverse = queueHead;
    while(traverse!=NULL){
        cout << "height " << traverse->ppl->height << endl;
        traverse = traverse->next;
    }
}

void addNode(Queue*& queue, const people ppl){

    people* node = new people;
    node->name = ppl.name;
    node->height = ppl.height;
    node->weight = ppl.weight;

    Queue* traverse = queue;
    Queue* new_node = new Queue;
    while(traverse!= NULL){
        traverse= traverse->next;
    }
    new_node->ppl = node;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    traverse=new_node;
    traverse->next = NULL;
    }

int main(){
    Queue * queueHead = new Queue;

    people * node = new people;
    node->name = Ashley;
    node->height = 5.5;
    node->weight = 125;
    queueHead->ppl = node;
    queueHead->next = NULL;
    node=NULL;

people node2 = {
    .name = Peter,
    .height = 5.8,
    .weight = 145
};

people node3 = {
    .name = Bill,
    .height = 6.0,
    .weight = 160
};

people node4 = {
    .name = Mike,
    .height = 6.2,
    .weight = 150
};

people node5 = {
    .name = Chris,
    .height = 6.2,
    .weight = 140
};

addNode(queueHead,node2);
addNode(queueHead,node3);
addNode(queueHead,node4);
addNode(queueHead,node5);
//queueHead->next = NULL;

print(queueHead);
```

Comment: It took me a while to find the start of your `main` function; you may want to clean up the indentation if you want more people to look at this. Also, you've already figured out that there is a problem adding nodes. Have you used a debugger to step through `addNode` to verify it does what you think it does? (Hint: in its current form, `traverse` is useless.)

Comment: `while(traverse!=NULL){ traverse= traverse->next; }` is a silly way of writing `traverse = nullptr;`

Comment: Are you intentionally writing C++20 code?

Comment: I suspect it is C code with a few of C++-isims. Are designated member initialization slotted for inclusion in C++20 (COOL!), or is there something else, @NeilButterworth ?

Comment: @user45 Apparently https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

In `addNode`

```
Queue* traverse = queue;
```

is a copy of the address of `queue` this means they point to the same place, but that's not all that helpful. As an example, note what happens with the loop iterating to the end of the list:

```
while(traverse->next != NULL){
    traverse= traverse->next;
}
```

Iterates through the list, but it leaves you with `traverse` pointing to NULL every time, and it's separate from anything attached to the list.

```
traverse=new_node;
```

assigns the new node to `traverse`, but traverse is a local variable that merely pointed to the same thing as the last node's `next`. traverse drops out of scope, the list is not updated, and the new node is leaked.

But

```
Queue** traverse = &queue;
```

lets `traverse` always point to a `next`, not just be a copy of a next. If you update `*traverse`, you can modify the list. For example,

```
void addNode(Queue*& queue, const people ppl){ 
 // I think you dropped a & here const pass by value isn't all that useful.

    people* node = new people;
    node->name = ppl.name;
    node->height = ppl.height;
    node->weight = ppl.weight;
    // the above should be done in a people copy constructor

    Queue** traverse = &queue;
    Queue* new_node = new Queue;
    while((*traverse)!= NULL){
        traverse= &(*traverse)->next; //traverse points at next instead of
                                      // being a copy.
    }
    new_node->ppl = node;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    *traverse=new_node; // pointing what traverse points at at the new node 
    (*traverse)->next = NULL; // this should really be done in a Queue constructor
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your add node function never actually adds the new node the existing queue.

Try this instead

```
void addNode(Queue*& queue, const people ppl){

    people* node = new people;
    node->name = ppl.name;
    node->height = ppl.height;
    node->weight = ppl.weight;

    Queue* traverse = queue;
    Queue* new_node = new Queue;

    while(traverse->next != NULL){
        traverse= traverse->next;
    }
    new_node->ppl = node;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    traverse->next = new_node;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed the error. Do you mind explain why traverse need to be a pointer to a pointer in this case?

Comment: In this code its not a pointer to a pointer. Its a pointer to a node in the list, and you have to go through the list until you find the last node, and then update that node.

Comment: @FannyZhang I think you have asked this in the wrong answer. With `Queue* traverse`, `traverse` only knows where the next link *is*. You cannot use this information to link the new node to the existing list. To make a single pointer work, you have to maintain a second pointer to store the address of the the last visited node so you can update the last visited node with the new node. With a pointer to a pointer, `Queue ** traverse;`, `traverse` knows where the next link *goes*, eliminating the need for extra book keeping tracking the last node.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed info. I understand better now.